# React/Typescript/mui- Help understanding abstraction over a third party component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, wrapper, encapsulation

We started a project and implemented several pages using material ui's React library. We use React hooks exclusively. I was told to create a wrapper around the mui DataGrid. The purpose behind the decision was that a particular page would need functionality that the DataGrid probably doesn't have. A special case, and one which we don't know the specific needs of at this point. I'm a relative newbie with React and Typescript and I don't even know how you go about creating wrappers, especially with a component as large and feature rich as mui's DataGrid. Where to start?  I started like this:

```
import {
  DataGrid as DataGridWrapper,
  GridColumns,
  GridLocaleText,
  GridRowsProp,
  GridFilterModel,
  GridSortModel,
  GridCallbackDetails,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import AddBoxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddBox";
import { esES } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { enUS } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

export interface GridProps {
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  gridColumns: GridColumns; 
  gridRows: GridRowsProp;
  gridPageSize?: number;
  showAddButton?: boolean;
  onAddButtonClick?: () => void; 
  onFilterModelChange?: (model: GridFilterModel, details: GridCallbackDetails) => void;
  onSortModelChange?: (model: GridSortModel, details: GridCallbackDetails) => void;
}

function DataGrid({
  style,
  gridColumns,
  gridRows,
  gridPageSize = 10,
  showAddButton = true,
  onAddButtonClick,
  onFilterModelChange,
  onSortModelChange,
  
}: GridProps) {
  const strings = useLocalizedStrings();
  
  // use text translations from the grid and apply them to all pages
  let localeTextTranslations : Partial<GridLocaleText>  
  if (strings.getLanguage() === "es") {
      localeTextTranslations = esES.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText;
  } else {
      localeTextTranslations = enUS.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {showAddButton && (
        <div style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
            <Tooltip title="Add">
                  <IconButton
                      aria-label="add"
                      color="primary"
                      onClick={() => {
                          onAddButtonClick?.()
                      }}
                  >
                      <AddBoxIcon />
                  </IconButton>
              </Tooltip>
        </div>
      )}
      <div style={{ height: 700, width: "100%" }}>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%" }}>
          <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <DataGridWrapper
              columns={gridColumns}
              rows={gridRows}
              style={style}
              hideFooterSelectedRowCount={true}
              pageSize={gridPageSize}
              onFilterModelChange={onFilterModelChange}
              onSortModelChange={onSortModelChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default DataGrid;
```

At this point I started wondering what the benefit of doing this is, if I'm simply duplicating the mui interface. Plus, I don't know how to handle the typings. Do I create new types that wrap mui's types? That seems like it could get complicated pretty fast as everything in mui has underlying types and so do those types, many levels deep. Or should consumers import the types from mui directly like I have here where I'm typing my props as mui types (but that seems wrong and against the idea of abstraction).

So if I'm not really encapsulating logic and am instead simply renaming props, does this even make sense to do? How does one approach such a task? In the end, this just feels weird so far. To make all pages use something in basically the same way you would use the actual mui grid. I feel like I'm missing something.

Can someone give me an example of some patterns I would use to make this actually be the start of a proper wrapper? And how to handle the typings required by mui and translating those to what's exposed to consumers? Or any thoughts at all? I searched for creating 3rd party wrapper components in React and only saw stuff with classes and higher order components. Nothing with hooks. In the end, I guess my specific questions are:

1. how to create a basic wrapper?
2. how to handle typings of the thing you wrap?
3. any considerations I should keep in mind?

I almost don't know what I don't know so it's difficult to be specific. I wish I could find some examples.